# What's the difference between the lenses EF-S 18-55 DC III and EF-S 18-55 IS II?

Tags: lens, kit-lens, image-stabilization

I'm planning on purchasing a Canon 1100D with an image stabilized lens.

However, I've found two offers with different lenses. Can you explain to me the difference?

1. **[Canon EOS 1100D + EF-S 18-55 IS II](http://www.preissuchmaschine.de/in-Digitalkamera/SLR-10-Megapixel/Canon-EOS-1100D-EF-S-18-55-IS-II.html)**
2. **[Canon EOS 1100D + EF-S 18-55 DC III](http://www.preissuchmaschine.de/in-Digitalkamera/SLR-10-Megapixel/Canon-EOS-1100D-EF-S-18-55-DC-III.html)**

A similar offer on [amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/Canon-SLR-Digitalkamera-Megapixel-HD-Ready-Live-View/dp/B004MKNBKU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1334576259&sr=8-1&tag=acleint-21) suggests that offer 1 has an image stabilizer, but I don't know about offer 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Canon's overview for lenses with EF-S mounts](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/ef-s.html) does *not* use the descripton **DC**. The reason for why several third-party resellers use this description remains unclear to me

[This list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_lens_mount#List_of_EF-S_lenses) on Wikipedia suggests that the **DC** version of the lense is the basically the same, but without image stabilization.

### Block diagrams

(source: Canon)

**[EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/ef-s/ef_s18%7E55_35%7E56iii.html?p=2)**

[image]

**[EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/ef-s/ef_s18-55_35-56_is_ii.html?p=2)**

[image]

### Description

(source: Canon)

**[EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/ef-s/ef_s18%7E55_35%7E56iii.html?p=1)**

> The Canon EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III is a lightweight, compact standard zoom lens specifically for cameras that take EF-S lenses.
> Featuring a high-precision aspherical lens element, the lens
> compensates for chromatic aberrations that can occur while zooming to
> deliver high-resolution, high-contrast imaging performance. Through
> optimized lens positioning and coatings, the model greatly minimizes
> the flare and ghosting commonly associated with digital camera
> photography.  It is a worthy successor to the EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 II
> and features a revamped external design.

**[EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II](http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/lens/ef/data/ef-s/ef_s18-55_35-56_is_ii.html?p=1)**

> The new Canon EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II inherits the highly regarded
> optical design utilized in its predecessor, the EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6
> IS, released in September 2007. Featuring a high-precision aspherical
> lens element, the lens compensates for chromatic aberrations that can
> occur while zooming to deliver high-resolution, high-contrast imaging
> performance. Through optimized lens positioning and coatings, the
> model greatly minimizes the flare and ghosting commonly associated
> with digital camera photography. Furthermore, the EF-S18-55mm
> f/3.5-5.6 IS II includes an optimized control algorithm that has been
> aligned with the Image Stabilizer structure and characteristics,
> achieving image stabilization equivalent to approximately four
> shutter-speed stops.
>
> Based on a shutter speed of "1/(focal length x 1.6)" seconds, considered the limit to prevent hand shake during hand-held
> photography.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [This Post](http://www.photoreview.com.au/news/canon-unveils-new-lenses) (at the bottom)

> The new EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III lens. (Source: Canon.) The EF-S
>   18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III is a standard zoom lens that is light and
>   compact and will replace the standard kit lens with future EOS kits.
>   It includes aspherical lenses and coatings plus a redesign that
>   positions elements to minimise ghosting and flare. Consisting of 11
>   elements in 9 groups it has a circular aperture and optimised AF
>   control.

Looks like a non-stabilised version

> The new EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II lens. (Source: Canon.) The EF-S
>   18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II is a second-generation standard zoom lens with
>   built-in image stabilisation that provides a shutter speed advantage
>   of approximately four f-stops. Light and compact, is has a similar
>   optical design to the EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III and weighs only 200
>   grams.

You should make a choice based on sample images and functionality - look at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) and find the specific lens group

Answer (score -2):

I have heard that although the IS version has image stabilisation, the lens itself is a lot slower and has a smaller AP thus giving it a disadvantage in low light conditions. Whereas the DC version will perform better in lower light conditions. Based on that, and the fact that I enjoy low light stills in general, I decided to get the DC version.

Comment: The aperture is the same for both models. Focus motor is probably also the same. IMHO get the stabilized one. And if you can, get the stm version (newer, IS and super fast and silent focusing). IS will help a lot on low light situations, given hat both lenses have the same aperture.

Comment: This is completely, totally and utterly false. The two lenses have *exactly* the same optical design, just the IS element is fixed in place in the DC version. And f/3.5 to f/5.6 isn't good for low light in any case - you're much better off with the nifty fifty for that.

Comment: @tony You seem to be confusing the EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II (2011) with the much newer EF-S 18-55mm f/4-5.6 IS STM (2017).