# What does "Kit DFIN III" means in CANON EOS 750D?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-design, canon-700d

I have search around for "Kit DFIN III", but didnot find any reference. What is the difference between

1. CANON EOS 750D Kit DFIN III SLR 24.2 Megapixel with lens 18-55 mm f /
   5.6, 7.7 cm Touchscreen, WLAN

**And**

2. CANON EOS 750D SLR Camera 24.2 Megapixel with Lens 18-55 mm f / 3.5-5.6, 7.7 cm Touchscreen, WLAN

Ref:
http://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_canon-eos-750d-kit-dfin-iii-2257432.html

Comment: Please post back if you discover what DFIN stands for. I am curious myself, and cannot find the information elsewhere.

Comment: @osullic I think they are referring to  [EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 III](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/22548) as 'Kit DFIN III' still don't know this 'DFIN' abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canon does not have "DFIN" in names of their products. "DFIN" (whatever it means) is an invention of MediaMarkt. Therefore there is no difference between the two variants mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

The lenses on them are different —> ef-s versus is, stm. The lather has a stabliser. I think that explains the difference in price. I’m